# Populating Datatables with php sending json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, datatables

I'm having troubles identify the problem in my code.

I'm doing a searching script, and I'd like to show the results in Datatable. I have a searching form that sends data to my php file and returns a json_encode of my query results, then on ajax success, I build my table passing the results in "data": response.

The query worked just fine when I was doing it without Datatables, but since I need pagination and stuff, I need it to work on Datatables.

HTML for Table:

```
<div id="results">

        <table id="example" class="display compact hover stripe" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>

                <th>Cognome</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <th>Provincia</th>
                <th>Tipo Cliente</th>
                <th>Amministrazione</th>
                <th>Stato</th>
                <th>Fonte</th>
                <th>Data Ricezione</th>
                <th></th>

            </thead>          
        </table>

    </div>
```

Javascript for Datatable:

```
$('#submit_src').on("click", function() { 

    $.ajax({
        data: $("#ricerca").serialize(), 
        type: $("#ricerca").attr('method'), 
        url: $("#ricerca").attr('action'),
        success: function(response) {

            $('#example').dataTable( {
                "data": response,
                "sPaginationType": "listbox",
                "bFilter": false,
                "jQueryUI": true,
                "processing": true,
                'iDisplayLength': 25,
            } );
        }

    });
    return false;
});
```

"submit_src" is my button for submit ofcourse, and "ricerca" is the name of my form.

The json code I get is:

```
{"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":"35036","iTotalDisplayRecords":"1","aaData":[["stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff"]]}
```

Error:

```
DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

This link may help with what you are trying to accomplish: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html. It explains that DataTables expects arrays for the data; however, in order to use the objects it can be done by using the columns.data option.

I have also used DataTables without `<tbody>` so that should not be an issue.

Edit:
Try the following, I was able to get the 'stuff' to show in the table:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "data": response.aaData
} );
```

Edit 2:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var response = {
       "sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":"35036","iTotalDisplayRecords":"1",
       "aaData": [
       ["stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff"]]
    };

    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "data": response.aaData,
        //"sPaginationType": "listbox",
        "bFilter": false,
        "jQueryUI": true,
        "processing": true,
        'iDisplayLength': 25
    } );

});
```

Comment: I've tried to use 'response.aaData', but I still don't get any errors and the table is not populated. Since the query works, and the json is correctly sent to my script, I guess it is either a format of my json wich it's not correct, or maybe I'm handling it the wrong way.

Comment: @Dankorw try out my second edit. Your json should be okay, I made the response match yours exactly. I'm wondering if the problem is with that sPaginationType because I could not get it to work until I commented that out.

Comment: It looks like sPaginationType takes two options, 'two_button' and 'full_numbers.' When I put: 'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers' it worked.

Comment: Removing 'sPaginationType' and useing your script gives me a void table. I'm getting the same json {"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":"35036","iTotalDisplayRecords":"1","aaData":[["stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff","stuff"]]}

Comment: When you say used the script, you didn't use the entire thing right? I put that much to show I was matching your environment as much as I could. Since the json coming back is okay, you should just need the snippet where it's assigning the 'example' table to dataTable. Is it possible to post your updated jQuery code that you are trying?

Comment: Here, I made a JSFiddle to let you see my script part of the page. http://jsfiddle.net/27hcyza1/ Am I doing this right?

Comment: That looks correct to me and what I was doing...BUT that is all based on your json coming back in that exact format as you have given. If you still are having trouble feel free to email me, as we don't want to flood this with comments. I'll be happy to help more.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the option

```
        dataType : "json",
```

on you code. That might confuse the type of data recieved from the ajax script if not specified.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `<tbody></tbody>` is required with DataTables so it knows where to put the data returned. Try adding that to your `table#example`.

```
    <table id="example" class="display compact hover stripe" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>

            <th>Cognome</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Telefono</th>
            <th>Provincia</th>
            <th>Tipo Cliente</th>
            <th>Amministrazione</th>
            <th>Stato</th>
            <th>Fonte</th>
            <th>Data Ricezione</th>
            <th></th>

        </thead> 
        <tbody></tbody>         
    </table>
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. I've added the error I get from the alert once I submit my form so it's easier to debug it.

Comment: What happens when you make `response` into `response['aaData']` ?

Comment: The error doesn't show up, but the table is not populated. Alerting response['aaData'] is showing 'undefined'.